# Mark a reference type parameter as "contents will be changed"?

Tags: c#, pass-by-reference

I'm passing an object like a List for example to a function.

How can I show to the caller that this function will actually change the contents of that List/Array/etc?

At the moment, I put it in the function comment. Is there a "formal" way to indicate that?

Comment: Quick answer is no. There are no guidelines regarding notifying the caller of changes to an object. The only thing you can do is review the documentation and \ or the method documentation. If you are writing a method that you wish to notify on changes you can try implementing INotifyPropertyChaged (or similar events).

Comment: The `out` keyword would be one way.. although it would only enforce the reference.. not adding/removing items from the list.

Comment: A method return value is always a very good hint.

Answer (score 1):

There unfortunately isn't a formal way.

The best you can do is to make the parameter type `IEnumerable<T>` instead (if you can), or you could use [`ReadOnlyCollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132474.aspx) or [`IReadOnlyList<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh192385.aspx) in order to express that the method *won't* change the list (the opposite of what you're asking).

Note that if you use `IReadOnlyList<T>`, the caller will NOT have to convert a the parameter if you pass an array OR a list, which is quite handy:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Demo
{
    class Program
    {
        void run()
        {
            List<int> list = new List<int> {1};
            test(list); // Caller can just pass list, although method accepts IReadOnlyList<int>

            int[] array = new int[10];
            test(array); // Works with arrays too.
        }

        void test(IReadOnlyList<int> data)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(data.Count);
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            new Program().run();
        }
    }
}
```

Thinking about it, I'd perhaps go as far as to say that using `IReadOnlyList<T>` *is* a formal formal way to express this.

However this is the *opposite* of what you were asking. It tells you that the method *won't* change the list passed to it. Unfortunately there's definitely no formal way to express that a method *will* change the list (other than documenting the method).

In the absence of documentation stating otherwise, you have to assume that any method *could* change a list passed to it.

Answer (score 0):

not sure if this is *formal*, but you can use [code contract](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264808.aspx) like

```
Contract.Ensures(((IArray)arr).Count != Contract.OldValue(((IArray)arr).Count));
```

or

```
Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<IArray>() != ....
```

depend on your needs.

**Im actually thinking a unit test is the most *formal* way** :)